# Find where line-segments intersect with a box

Tags: math, language-agnostic, geometry, lines

I am trying to figure out where a bunch of line-segments clip into a window around them. I saw the [Liang–Barsky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liang%E2%80%93Barsky_algorithm) algorithm, but that seems to assume the segments already clip the edges of the window, which these do not.

Say I have a window from `(0,0)` to `(26,16)`, and the following segments:

```
(7,6) - (16,3)
(10,6) - (19,6)
(13,10) - (21,3)
(16,12) - (19,14)
```

**Illustration:**

[image]

I imagine I need to extend the segments to a certain `X` or `Y` point, till they hit the edge of the window, but I don't know how.

How would I find the points where these segments (converted to lines?) clip into the edge of the window? I will be implementing this in C#, but this is pretty language-agnostic.

Comment: Your question is not clear. You sometimes ask about "lines" but you do not define any, only "line segments." Are you asking where the lines that contain the line segments will intersect the border of the viewing window, or something else? "Clipping" usually means removing the parts of a figure that lie outside the viewing window, but that does not seem to be what you mean. You never give the viewing windows for your example. And so on.

Comment: @RoryDaulton My geometry terminology is not up to snuff, I wrote those in error. All I have are line segments. This is why I included the annotation to ensure clarity if my verbiage was incorrect.

Comment: Downvoter, care to explain why the question is off-topic or unclear? @RoryDaulton The picture clearly shows the window, and should succinctly make up for my ignorance of the proper verbiage to describe my problem. If I take those segments and extend them, how do I find the points where the hit the window/box that is in that image. I am not sure how you are having a difficult time understanding the question :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure this out.

I can extend my lines to the edge of the box by first finding the equations of my lines, then solving for the `X` and `Y` of each of the sides to get their corresponding point. This requires passing the max and min `Y` and the max and min `X` into the following functions, returning 4 values. If the point is outside the bounds of the box, it can be ignored.

My code is in C#, and is making extension methods for EMGU's `LineSegment2D`. This is a .NET wrapper for OpenCv.

My Code:

```C#
    public static float GetYIntersection(this LineSegment2D line, float x)
    {
        Point p1 = line.P1;
        Point p2 = line.P2;

        float dx = p2.X - p1.X;
        if(dx == 0)
        {
            return float.NaN;
        }

        float m = (p2.Y - p1.Y) / dx; //Slope
        float b = p1.Y - (m * p1.X); //Y-Intercept
        return m * x + b;
    }

    public static float GetXIntersection(this LineSegment2D line, float y)
    {
        Point p1 = line.P1;
        Point p2 = line.P2;

        float dx = p2.X - p1.X;
        if (dx == 0)
        {
            return float.NaN;
        }

        float m = (p2.Y - p1.Y) / dx; //Slope
        float b = p1.Y - (m * p1.X); //Y-Intercept
        return (y - b) / m;
    }
```

I can then take these points, check if they are in the bounds of the box, discard the ones that are not, remove duplicate points (line goes directly into corner). This will leave me with one `x` and one `y` value, which I can then pair to the corresponding min or max `Y` or `X` values I passed into the functions to make 2 points. I can then make my new segment with the two points.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two line segments *P* and *Q* with points

```
P0 - P1
Q0 - Q1
```

The  line equations are

```
P = P0 + t(P1 - P0)
Q = Q0 + r(Q1 - Q0)
```

then to find out where they intersect after extension you need to solve the following equation for *t* and *r*

```
P0 + t(P1 - P0) = Q0 + r(Q1 - Q0)
```

The following code can do this. ( Extracted from my own code base )

```
    public static (double t, double r )? SolveIntersect(this Segment2D P, Segment2D Q)
    {
        // a-d are the entries of a 2x2 matrix
        var a = P.P1.X - P.P0.X;
        var b = -Q.P1.X + Q.P0.X;
        var c = P.P1.Y - P.P0.Y;
        var d = -Q.P1.Y + Q.P0.Y;

        var det = a*d - b*c;
        if (Math.Abs( det ) < Utility.ZERO_TOLERANCE)
            return null;

        var x = Q.P0.X - P.P0.X;
        var y = Q.P0.Y - P.P0.Y;

        var t = 1/det*(d*x - b*y);
        var r = 1/det*(-c*x + a*y);

        return (t, r);

    }
```

If null is returned from the function then it means the lines are parallel and cannot intersect. If a result is returned then you can do.

```
    var result = SolveIntersect( P, Q );
    if (result != null)
    {
        var ( t, r) = result.Value;
        var p = P.P0 + t * (P.P1 - P.P0);
        var q = Q.P0 + t * (Q.P1 - Q.P0);
        // p and q are the same point of course
    }
```

The extended line segments will generally intersect more than one box edge but only one of those intersections will be inside the box. You can check this easily.

```
   bool IsInBox(Point corner0, Point corner1, Point test) =>
      (test.X > corner0.X && test.X < corner1.X && test.Y > corner0.Y && test.Y < corner1.Y ;
```

That should give you all you need to extend you lines to the edge of your box.

Answer (score 0):

Wiki  description of Liang-Barsky algorithm  is not bad, but code is flaw.

Note: this algorithm intended **to throw out** lines without intersection as soon as possible. If most of lines intersect the rectangle, then approach from your answer might be rather effective, otherwise L-B algorithm wins.

[This page](http://www.skytopia.com/project/articles/compsci/clipping.html) describes approach in details and contains concise effective code:

```
// Liang-Barsky function by Daniel White @ http://www.skytopia.com/project/articles/compsci/clipping.html
// This function inputs 8 numbers, and outputs 4 new numbers (plus a boolean value to say whether the clipped line is drawn at all).
//
bool LiangBarsky (double edgeLeft, double edgeRight, double edgeBottom, double edgeTop,   // Define the x/y clipping values for the border.
                  double x0src, double y0src, double x1src, double y1src,                 // Define the start and end points of the line.
                  double &x0clip, double &y0clip, double &x1clip, double &y1clip)         // The output values, so declare these outside.
{

    double t0 = 0.0;    double t1 = 1.0;
    double xdelta = x1src-x0src;
    double ydelta = y1src-y0src;
    double p,q,r;

    for(int edge=0; edge<4; edge++) {   // Traverse through left, right, bottom, top edges.
        if (edge==0) {  p = -xdelta;    q = -(edgeLeft-x0src);  }
        if (edge==1) {  p = xdelta;     q =  (edgeRight-x0src); }
        if (edge==2) {  p = -ydelta;    q = -(edgeBottom-y0src);}
        if (edge==3) {  p = ydelta;     q =  (edgeTop-y0src);   }   

        if(p==0 && q<0) return false;   // Don't draw line at all. (parallel line outside)

        r = q/p; 

        if(p<0) {
            if(r>t1) return false;         // Don't draw line at all.
            else if(r>t0) t0=r;            // Line is clipped!
        } else if(p>0) {
            if(r<t0) return false;      // Don't draw line at all.
            else if(r<t1) t1=r;         // Line is clipped!
        }
    }

    x0clip = x0src + t0*xdelta;
    y0clip = y0src + t0*ydelta;
    x1clip = x0src + t1*xdelta;
    y1clip = y0src + t1*ydelta;

    return true;        // (clipped) line is drawn
}
```